# True or False statements about compactness of Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness

Several statements I like to know their True or False statements about the **compactness of Lie group**.

1. **Semi-simple Lie algebra**: Every semi-simple Lie group generated by the semi-simple Lie algebra is compact.
2. **Non-semi-simple Lie algebra**: Non-semi-simple Lie group generated by the non-semi-simple Lie algebra is compact, **if and only if** the non-semi-simple Lie group is the **direct product of compact U(1)$^N$ Abelian group and other semi-simple Lie groups**.
3. In general, the Lie group is compact, **if and only if**, the Lie algebra can be written as the direct product of U(1)$^N$ Abelian Lie algebra and other semi-simple Lie algebra.
4. In general, the Lie group is compact, if and only if, the Lie algebra can be written as the direct product of U(1)$^N$ Abelian Lie algebra and other **compact semi-simple Lie algebra**.

True or False? If True, please provide your reasoning. If False, please give counter examples.

Comment: What examples did you consider before asking this? Notice that Qiaochu's examples involve nothing more elaborate that what is surely the simplest possible example!

Comment: Sorry, what I really should ask is the 4: In general, the Lie group is compact, if and only if, the Lie algebra can be written as the direct product of U(1)$^N$ Abelian Lie algebra and other **compact semi-simple Lie algebra**.

Comment: Do edit the question to reflect your intended question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is false. For example, $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, but $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn't compact.
2. This is also false, and a counterexample to 1 also provides a counterexample here. For example, $U(1) \times SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn't compact.
3. This is also false, and a counterexample to 2 also provides a counterexample here.

The term you want to look up is [compact Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra). See also [compact real form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_%28Lie_theory%29#Compact_real_form).

Comment: Thanks +1. Sorry, what I really should ask is the 4: In general, the Lie group is compact, if and only if, the Lie algebra can be written as the direct product of U(1)$^N$ Abelian Lie algebra and other **compact semi-simple Lie algebra**. True or False?

Comment: @miss-tery: that's still a bit buggy. First of all, $U(1)$ is a Lie group, not a Lie algebra. If you mean the Lie algebra of $U(1)$, which is just $\mathbb{R}$, then of course $\mathbb{R}$ itself (the Lie group) is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks +1. Sorry, what I really should ask is the 4: In general, the Lie group is compact, if and only if, the Lie group can be written as the direct product of U(1)$^N$ Abelian Lie group and other compact semi-simple Lie group. True or False? (I will take Lie group as the one generated from some Lie algebra, so pardon me using it interchangeably. I am not a mathematician, but an engineer.)

Comment: @miss-tery: still not quite true. In particular it's possible to start with a compact Lie group of that form and quotient it by a "diagonal" central subgroup. For example, start with $U(1) \times SU(2)$, and quotient it by the subgroup generated by $(-1, -1)$.